# Developing Web Applications

Tags: php

I am learning how to develop web applications using php. I am trying to get this contact form to come up when you click the contact link but nothing happens. I have been over and over the pages and I do not see why it does not work.

Here is the  page:

```
// Determine what page to display:
switch ($p) {

    case 'about':
        $page = 'about.inc.php';
        $page_title = 'About This Site';
        break;

    case 'this':
        $page = 'this.inc.php';
        $page_title = 'This is Another Page.';
        break;

    case 'that':
        $page = 'that.inc.php';
        $page_title = 'That is Also a Page.';
        break;

    case 'contact':
        $page = 'contact.inc.php';
        $page_title = 'Contact Us';
        break;

    case 'search':
        $page = 'search.inc.php';
        $page_title = 'Search Results';
        break;

    // Default is to include the main page.
    default:
        $page = 'main.inc.php';
        $page_title = 'Site Home Page';
        break;

} // End of main switch.

// Make sure the file exists:
if (!file_exists('./modules/' . $page)) {
    $page = 'main.inc.php';
    $page_title = 'Site Home Page';
}
```

And here is the last one:

```
    <div id="navigation">
        <ul id="navlist">
            <li><a href="index.php">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="index.php?p=about">About Us</a></li>
            <li><a href="index.php?p=this">This</a></li>
            <li><a href="index.php?p=that">That</a></li>
            <li><a href="index.php?p=contact">Contact</a></li>
<li><p><strong>A tiny little service announcement.</strong><br/>Please contact us with any questions. </p></li>
        </ul>
```

The error I am getting is when you click on the link that says contact in the navigation system does not do anything. It is suppose to go to the contact.inc.php so the form shows and the person can fill out. I have been over the code many times and I am not seeing why it will not go over to the contact.inc.php.

Edit: I even tried to change the index.php?p=contact to contact.inc.php and nothing happens either.

Edit: Here is a link to my page. Now if you click on the contact you will see it does not take you to the contact page.http://www.elinkswap.com/snorris/index.php

Comment: Posting large blocks of code and expecting people to go over them for you won't get you far. In what way doesn't it work? Are you getting error messages? What are your expected and actual results. Can you isolate the bits of code that are causing problems?

Comment: Try reducing the code snippets to the bare minimum, it will help you isolate the problem, as well as all others. You are in fact asking others to debug your application this way. You might even find that you can answer your own question by doing this.

Comment: It looks like you need to know about [`heredoc`](http://php.net/heredoc) strings.

Comment: Just start with an echo $p; before the switch in your 2nd file to see if the problem is there..

Comment: What does "do nothing" mean? Does it show the main page? A blank page? Errors?

Comment: Try `switch($_REQUEST["p"])` in place of `switch($p)`, and enable `error_reporting(E_ALL);` beforehand.

Comment: when I mean do nothing it does not go over to the contact page like it is suppose to it stays on that the main page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to use [Register Globals](http://php.net/manual/en/security.globals.php) which is highly discouraged. Instead, access the GET variable explicitly by using switch (`$_GET['p']`). Additionally check for the existence of `$_GET['p']` before using `isset()`.

Comment: No, he isn't. In the [original revision](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/8211713/revisions#revd5d90064-2753-4d45-aff9-c6832856ec49) of his post he accessed $_GET to get $p. (The isset check won't exactly make debugging easier.)

Answer (score 0):

Try to use debugging tools and place breakpoints at possible areas, if you need to do manual debugging, you could echo a message and die try replacing the code below:

```
// Make sure the file exists:
if (!file_exists('./modules/' . $page)) {
  $page = 'main.inc.php';
  $page_title = 'Site Home Page';
   echo "$page file didnt exist";
   die();
}
```

if you you see the file didn't exist, means you know your ./modules/$page didn't exist and 
**the $page is overwritten with main.inc.php**, therefore you have to make sure your folders and files are correctly placed.